# Firefox logout issue in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, firefox

I am trying to logout from my application in Mozilla Firefox but when I click on logout button it redirecting me on dashboard page. It works only when I delete browser history.

```
function logout()
 {
     $this->user_id = $this->flexi_auth->get_user_id();
     if ($this->flexi_auth->logout_specific_user($this->user_id) === true)
         {
         $this->session->unset_userdata('is_searched');
         redirect('auth/login');
         }
 }
```

When I click on logout button in Firefox then it redirecting on dashboard page, unable to call above function.

It happening only in Firefox browser. Please help me; how can I resolve it?

Comment: Comment code inside logout function and just add `echo 'here'` and test you reach the function

Comment: yes i wrote  echo "test";die;  but did not reach the function

Comment: don't use die. Its hangs in CI. Do in my way.

Comment: Hi Abdulla,
I did in your way.

function logout() { echo 'here';
       /* $this->user_id = $this->flexi_auth->get_user_id();
        if ($this->flexi_auth->logout_specific_user($this->user_id) === true) {
            $this->session->unset_userdata('is_searched');
            redirect('auth/login');
        }*/
    }

But not reaching to the function in firefox only.

Comment: Show me your logout function

Comment: Add in your Question

Comment: function is written in question.

Comment: I mean view code. Logout Button

Comment: <a href="<?php echo base_url('auth/logout'); ?>"><span>Logout</span></a>

Comment: Is any routes there for this??

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = "auth/login";
in routes.php

Comment: any luck with this

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this where yo ucan edit the code according to your variable names..

```
$user_data = $this->session->all_userdata();
        foreach ($user_data as $key => $value) {
            if ($key != 'session_id' && $key != 'ip_address' && $key != 'user_agent' && $key != 'last_activity') {
                $this->session->unset_userdata($key);
            }
        }
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('auth/login');
```

Comment: Hi Vivek, 
The above code will run if the function gets call, the problem is, it's unable to call logout function in firefox, it redirecting on dashboard page on each click of logout.

Comment: how are you calling the logout function by button or some link there might be some issues regarding html and css that is why in firefox it not clicking

Comment: HI Vivek,
following is the link
<a href="https://www.test.com/auth/logout"><span>Logout</span></a>

Comment: did u tried like this <a href="<?php echo base_url('auth/logout')?>"><span>Logout</span></a>

Comment: is there any function in that controller or not ?

Comment: yes there are many function in auth controller including logout() function.

Comment: other functions is working fine or not of that particular controller?